# looking for a good reference for consuming feeds with RoR (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed

Hey, I'm writing a personal bookmarking application, and looking for a way to keep track of favorite feeds.
All written in Rails.

Thanks

Comment: So, you're looking for a library that handles RSS and Atom feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Feedzirra](http://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) in several applications and really like it.

It can do some things I forgot about at first, like sanitizing the HTML to help prevent against bad-HTML like scripts and other XSS attacks.